# How to filter output result and setup a range?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm making a Spanish-English dictionary crawler.

I want `# Part of Speech` to get result only in `<div id="dictionary-neodict-es">` range.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict

base_url = "https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/"
search_keyword = input("input the keyword : ")
url = base_url + search_keyword
spanishdict_r = requests.get(url)
spanishdict_soup = BeautifulSoup(spanishdict_r.text, 'html.parser')

# Phonetic Alphabet
print(spanishdict_soup.find("span", {"id": "dictionary-link-es"}).text)

# Part of Speech
part_of_speech = dict.fromkeys([x.text for x in spanishdict_soup.find_all("a", {"class": "href--2RDqa"})]).keys()
for part in part_of_speech:
    print(part)

# Meaning
print(spanishdict_soup.find("div", {"id": "quickdef1-es"}).text)
```

Why I'm telling you this is because there are three dictionary definitions available on SpanishDict.com website.

```
1. Curiosity Media Inc.
<div id="dictionary-neodict-es">

2. Harrap Publishers Limited
<div id="dictionary-neoharrap-es">

3. Collins Complete Spanish Electronic Dictionary © HarperCollins Publishers 2011
<div id="dictionary-collins-es">
```

You can see definition from `© Curiosity Media Inc.`at first.
Then you also can check other dictionary's definitions too.
So I only want to collect items from `© Curiosity Media Inc.` .

for example, [deifinition of modelo](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/modelo)

My crawler actually displays when I search `modelo`:

```
(moh-deh-loh)
masculine or feminine noun
masculine noun
adjective
Noun
model
```

> masculine or feminine noun <-- from "dictionary-neodict-es" OK
>
> masculine noun <-- from "dictionary-neodict-es" OK
>
> adjective <-- from "dictionary-neodict-es" OK
>
> Noun <-- collected from another dictionary's tag "dictionary-neoharrap-es", so it should not be displayed (or not to be parsed)
>
> model <-- from "dictionary-neodict-es" OK

So, my crawler should give me result as

```
(moh-deh-loh)
masculine or feminine noun
masculine noun
adjective
model
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `dictionary-neodict-es` tag.

Then find what you want to find in this scope.

```
# add dictionary-neodict-es tag
dictionary_neodict_es = spanishdict_soup.find("div", {"id": "dictionary-neodict-es"})

# use dictionary_neodict_es to find you need
dictionary_link_es = dictionary_neodict_es.find("span", {"id": "dictionary-link-es"})
part_of_speech = dict.fromkeys([x.text for x in dictionary_neodict_es.find_all("a", {"class": "href--2RDqa"})]).keys()
```